# Канвас блокирует скролл страницы на телефонах

Tags: css, reactjs, canvas

Реализовал канвас на реакте. Все отрабатывает так, как должно отрабатывать, но есть проблема: На телефонах скролл реализуется через тап, и когда пользователь хочет проскролить секцию с канваса, пытаясь проскролить через нажатие на сам канвас, то скролл не отрабатывает. Как можно решить такую проблему?

На самом канвасе выключен rotate и zoom

```
return (
        <div className={styles.iphone}>
            <Canvas className={styles.canvas} ref={element} orthographic>
                <OrbitControls scale={0.5} enableZoom={false} enableRotate={false} />
                <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault position={[1, 1, -10]} />
                <Environment preset='city' />
                <Suspense fallback={null}>
                    {!isOnePhone && (
                        <IphoneModel
                            positionZ={z1}
                            rotatePropY={-3}
                            rotatePropX={0}
                            rotatePropZ={0}
                            positionX={-14}
                        />
                    )}

                    <IphoneModel
                        positionZ={z2}
                        rotatePropY={-0.7}
                        rotatePropX={0}
                        rotatePropZ={0}
                        positionX={0}
                    />
                    {!isOnePhone && (
                        <IphoneModel
                            positionZ={z1}
                            rotatePropY={3}
                            rotatePropX={0}
                            rotatePropZ={0}
                            positionX={14}
                        />
                    )}
                </Suspense>
            </Canvas>
        </div>
    )
}
```